# How to use function return value in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am trying to get the returning value of a function into the svelte component.
However, my functions are structure in this way:

## GetData.svelte

```
<script>

  import { Modal, Button, Card } from "svelte-chota";


  let modal_open = false;
  let recordsObject = {};
  let records = [];
  
  const apiURL =
    "...src/Data/data.json";

  // Fetch data from the API
  async function getDataFromApi() {
    const response = await fetch(apiURL);
    recordsObject = await response.json();
    records = recordsObject.records;

    // Server responses is OK then
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("Success");
    } else {
      // Otherwise check the error
      throw new Error(response.status);
    }

    // Stats Functions
    // Count total records
    function countTotalRecords(totalRecord) {
      totalRecord = console.log(records.length);
      return totalRecord;
    }
    countTotalRecords();
}

</script>

<!-- Button to display stats -->
<Button on:click={(event) => (modal_open = true)}><pre> Stats</pre></Button>
<Modal bind:open={modal_open}>
  <Card>
    <div>
      <b><p>Below you will find the list of stats:</p></b>
      **<p>Total Records: {totalRecord}</p>**
      <p>Count of different event types:</p>
      <p>Min delay between intereactions:</p>
      <p>Max delay between intereactions:</p>
      <p>Mean delay between intereactions:</p>
      <p>Length of the longest sequence ("Topics filtered"):</p>
      <p>Total Time of All interactions:</p>
    </div>
  </Card>
</Modal>
```

The problem is this part:

```
<p>Total Records: {totalRecord}</p>
```

Error: 'totalRecord' is not defined svelte(missing-declaration)

I want to achieve is when I click on the model "Stats", the model will show up and must display the value {totalRecord}.

Please, is anybody able to help me to figure this out?
By searching on the internet. I have read that I would need to export variables or use bind, or stores... Honestly, I am a bit confused about how to achieve this.
Thank you

Comment: You have no variable called totalRecord, perhaps if you `let totalRecord = ""` up top by the other lets and then `totalRecord = records.count;` instead of the count function, it might work?

Comment: @James That worked!! I was going in the wrong direction and you saved me :) The only thing was I did `let totalRecord = 0` and `totalRecord = records.length` Thank you very much.  Maybe answer the question then I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need a variable declared to use it in a template. Then, when the value is available, you can update that variable.  Initially your template will show zero, then when the data loads it will change to be the right value.

```js
  import { Modal, Button, Card } from "svelte-chota";


  let modal_open = false;
  let recordsObject = {};
  let records = [];
  // variables declared here should be available in your templates, hopefully
  let totalRecord = 0;
  
  const apiURL =
    "...src/Data/data.json";

  // Fetch data from the API
  async function getDataFromApi() {
    const response = await fetch(apiURL);
    // Server responses is OK then
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("Success");
    } else {
      // Otherwise check the error
      throw new Error(response.status);
    }
    // do this after you know response.status is ok
    recordsObject = await response.json();
    records = recordsObject.records;
    // set the above variable to the right value
    totalRecord = records.length;
  }
```

Comment: It's not really user friendly to jump from a number to another in this case. I would encourage you to define `totalRecord` as `null` and show a loading animation until the real data is fetched.